# Save last variable value - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, variables, save

I have a function like this:

```
flag: boolean = false;

some_function(){
                var foo = some_num_value;
                var bar = foo;           // Trying to save value in a separate variable
                if(this.flag){
                               var total = bar + foo;
                             }
                   return total;
                   !this.flag;
               }
```

This above function runs 2 or 3 times in a single instance. The value of `var foo` changes for every iteration. I wish to save the value of each `var foo` such that I need to add it with the new value of `var foo` when the next iteration happens.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move foo to the outside of the method (function).

```
flag: boolean = false;
foo: number;

some_function(bar){
                
                

                if(this.flag){
                               var total = bar + foo;
                             }
                   this.foo += bar;
                   return total;
                   !this.flag;
               }
```

Comment: I found one method. I created an array and pushed all iterated values to that array. This array now stores all the values.